# <jsp:include page /> : couldn't load multiple nested <jsp:include page />

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I am using springMVC,and include pages with relative mapping.
But I couldn't load pages that multiple levels nested.

main.jsp:

```
<div id="mainInclude">
    <jsp:include page="/service/sjjggl/scriptRetrieve/newHotInclude"></jsp:include>
</div>
```

newHotInclude.jsp:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8 hidden-xs" id="showScriptNormal">
    <jsp:include page="/service/sjjggl/scriptRetrieve/showScriptNormal"></jsp:include>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    col-sm-4
    <jsp:include page="/service/sjjggl/scriptRetrieve/showScriptHot"></jsp:include>
</div>
</div>
```

I can not load `showScriptNormal.jsp` and `showScriptHot` in this way.

Is there a good way to realize multi-nested jsp pages?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try `<%@ include file="folder/.../BootstrapTag.jsp"%>` instead of `<jsp:include page="/service/sjjggl/scriptRetrieve/showScriptNormal">` ?

Comment: Thank you for your advice.`<%@ include file %>` just transfer a static page, but i need  the return data from `ModelAndView` .

Comment: I think it won't be a problem ! Try model and view as regular way !